# или что? / или что-то такое (в конце предложения)

Tags: запятые

Требуется ли запятая перед «или» при такой постановке: 
«У тебя совсем мозги отшибло(,) или что?» 
«Не волнуйся, через час они помирятся и будут попивать вместе чаёк(,) или ещё что-то в этом роде».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В обеих конструкциях нет запятых.

*У тебя совсем мозги отшибло или что?* Запятой нет, потому что **вопросительное предложение**. Независимо от того, каким Вы сочтёте предложение - простым с однородными членами (отшибло или мозги,  или что-то другое) или ССП (У тебя совсем мозги отшибло или что-то ещё случилось? Между двумя вопросительными предложениями в ССП запятых нет).
Если очень хочется сделать паузу, разделите на два предложения: *У тебя совсем мозги отшибло?  Или что?*

*Не волнуйся, через час они помирятся и будут попивать вместе чаёк(,) или ещё что-то в этом роде*. Нет запятой на основании наличия **общего члена "через час"**.

Answer (score 1):

В первом предложении запятая не нужна, т.к. в сложном вопросительном предложении происходит объединение простых предложений по смыслу за счет интонации (если под словом "что" подразумевать СИС с нулевым глаголом-связкой). Во втором же предложении возможны минимум 3 варианта в зависимости от того, что подразумевается под распространённым неопределённым местоимением "*ещё что-то в этом роде*" и связано ли оно со словом "*будут*":

"*Не волнуйся, через час они помирятся и будут попивать вместе чаёк(,) или ещё что-то в этом роде*".

1. В первом случае запятой может не быть на основании наличия **общего члена предложения** "*попивать*" - тогда подразумевается, что *попивать* будут или "*чаёк*", или *другой напиток* (обе фразы тут - это два разных **составных именных сказуемых**, у каждого из которых **своя именная часть** с **общим глаголом-связкой** "*попивать*" (и "*или*" тут разделяет **однородные члены предложения** - **именные связки**); можно даже сказать, что это одно большое составное именное сказуемое, где именная часть в общем виде обозначает понятие "*напитки*").
2. Во втором же случае в предложении может подразумеваться, что "*ещё что-то в этом роде*" - это не именная часть глагола "*попивать*", а **совершенно другое бытовое действие** (например, "*дурачиться*", "*мило болтать*"); тогда это либо **неопределённая форма составного глагольного сказуемого**, роль которой выполняет это распространённое неопределённое местоимение, в то время как роль **вспомогательного глагола** выполняет слово "*будут*", либо это **сказуемое, не связанное со словом "*будут*", а связанное напрямую с подлежащим "*они*"** (например, "*пойдут гулять*"); в первом случае после "*или*" подразумевается опущенное слово "*будут*" и запятая может ставиться только авторская, согласно интонации, - чтобы обособить одно действие от другого; а во втором случае, где "*или*" разделяет разрозненные части распространённого предложения (подлежащее и сказуемое), как раз по этой причине запятая и нужна (также, если бы слово "*будут*" не было бы опущено, и в первом случае нужна была бы запятая по этой же причине).